# Moving row between sheets at the top (instead of bottom)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, move

Currently, I am using the code below to move "finished" rows to a complete sheet. However, the rows are added at the bottom, creating an issue with my pivot tables (due to the range being extended).

Is anyone able to adjust this code to have the rows added to the top?

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (e.range.columnStart !== 19 || e.value !== "TRUE") return;
    e.source.getSheetByName("Complaints Current month")
        .appendRow(s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn())
            .getValues()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a.concat(b)
            }))
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Add some screenshots or link the sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sheet contains customer information and I am unable to share the sheet or create screenshots. I was hoping the script and explanation would be sufficient. Script now adds the line from one sheet to the overall sheet, however it is adding it at the bottom row and I am looking for adding the new line at the top row